# How to put a decimal point in the contingency table in R?

Tags: r, decimal

### My initial data are as follow:

```
birth <- c(rep(1,50),rep(0,34))
birth <- factor(birth, levels=c(1,0),
         labels=c("Birth Complications","No Birth Complications")) 
mental.health <- c(rep(1,30),rep(2,26),rep(3,28)) 
mental.health <- factor(mental.health, levels=c(1,2,3), 
labels=c("Normal","Depressed","Schizophrenic")) 
table(mental.health,birth)
```

---

But when I try to replace the numbers in each cell with the decimals(for instance, from 30 in the first cell to 30.5 and 6 to 6.5 in the bottom right cell), R says my rows and columns aren't equal length.

Here's the code I'm trying but not working:

```
birth <- c(rep(.5,101),rep(0.5,68))  
birth <- factor(birth, levels=c(1,0), labels=c("Birth 
Complications","No Birth Complications")) 
mental.health <- c(rep(2,120),rep(2,52),rep(3,56)) 
mental.health <- factor(mental.health, levels=c(1,2,3), 
labels=c("Normal","Depressed","Schizophrenic")) 
table(mental.health,birth)
```

What I did was to replace 1 with .5 then doubled the frequency of that number by changing from 50 to 101. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the birth list is now 101+68=169 posts whereas the mental health list is 120+52+56=228 posts... So yes, they are of different length...

Comment: The changed code is strange since you produce a birth vector containing the value 0.5 169 times, which does not fit the levels of the factor `(0,1)`. In addition the mental health factor contains 228 entries, so table won't work, as all entries have to be of the same length when calling table `(x,y)`

Comment: table() counts the values for each factor combination. Nothing you do to the data will produce decimals in a table of counts. You can however add values to the table, e.g. table(mental.health,birth)+.5
using your original data which will add 0.5 to each entry in the table.